# Dynamic header link not working need refresh angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am developing role based permission where now I need to display the links on the header and it is coming from the db.

After login I need to refresh the page in order to display dynamic links.

I have used ngx-permission and loading the permission array and checking the permission.

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  permissionData = null
  permissionModule = null
  useremail = null
  perm = [];

  constructor(
    private loginApi: LoginService,
    private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    console.log("Header constuctor")
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Header initialized')
    this.useremail = localStorage.getItem('useremail')
    this.perm.push(this.useremail)
    // console.log("User Email", this.useremail)
    this.checkUserPermissions()
  }

  logout() {
    this.loginApi.logout()
    this.router.navigate(['/login'])
  }

  checkUserPermissions() {
    let userID = localStorage.getItem('userid')
    if (userID) {
      this.loginApi.getAuthenticatedUserPermissions(userID).subscribe(res => {
        this.permissionModule = Object.keys(res[0].permissions[0])
        this.permissionData = res
        // ngx permission
        const perm = [];
        perm.push(this.permissionModule)
        this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(perm)
      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }

}
```

header.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="permissionModule?.length">
        <div *ngxPermissionsOnly="dashboard">
          <a routerLink="/barcharts">Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <div *ngxPermissionsOnly="product management">
          <a routerLink="/productmanagement">Product Management</a>
        </div>
        <div *ngxPermissionsOnly="app userlisting">
          <a routerLink="/appuserlisting_new">App User Listing</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: do you want it to refresh it on logging in

Comment: Nope I am developing SPA so there is no refresh concept.

Comment: yeah I know do you want to update the links list in logging

Comment: Yes but without refreshing page

Comment: yes you can do that just bind the links to the template angular will automatically update your  view

Comment: I don't know about it

Comment: have you get the links from the database to your angular app

Comment: Yes everything works but need to refresh the page.

Comment: is it populated in the perm array

Comment: I have edited answer check it now

Comment: did you correctly imported the module are there no any errors can you please verify by opening dev tools

Comment: Yes I have checked everything and there is nor problem..

Comment: does permisonmodule  array get populated

Comment: Yes it is.. I think I need to watch on variable changes..

Comment: verify whether it gets populated

Comment: it is working perfectly

Comment: can you put up the code in stackblitz so I can view it